# How to stop sugar syrup from crystallizing?

Tags: sugar

How much cream of tartar do you use to keep sugar syrup from crystallizing?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this recipe](http://www.chefeddy.com/2009/11/invert-sugar/), you will need about a gram for each kilogram of sugar. Roughly, this is about 1/3 to 1/4 of a teaspoon.

Try that and see if it works. If it doesn't, increase the amount slightly.